# Send @Model variable as parameter to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

**start reading at 'UPDATE'**

I have a *JavaScript* function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getAmount(AdminFee, TimeAndMatRate, TimeSpent, MinimumCharge) {
        var amount = math.Round(AdminFee + TimeAndMatRate * TimeSpent);
        if (amount < MinimumCharge) {
            amount = math.Round(MinimumCharge);
        }
        document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = amount;
    }
</script>
```

And I have the following field that has to be changed when I change another value:

```
 <span id="amount"></span>
```

When I change a value in this *textbox* the above field should be updated:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TimeAndMaterialsRate, new { onkeyup = "getAmount()" })
```

This code works fine as long as I do not try to send any parameters in `getAmount()`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work, could anyone please help me?

This is one of the things that I tried

```
 new { onkeyup = "getAmount("
     + @Model.AdminFee + ","
     + @Model.TimeAndMaterialsRate + ","
     + @Model.TotalTimeSpent.Hours + ","
     + @Model.MinimumCharge + ")"
 }
```

I also tried to above without '@'s

**UPDATE:**

The above code works now although it seems the function doesn't work properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getAmount(AdminFee, TimeAndMatRate, TimeSpent, MinimumCharge) {
        var amount = math.Round(AdminFee + TimeAndMatRate * TimeSpent);
        if (amount < MinimumCharge) {
            amount = math.Round(MinimumCharge);
        }
        document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = amount;
    }
</script>
```

The values passed into the function are `id`, `id`, `double`, `id`. Any clue on why this doesn't work?

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before it is sent to the view, so all you doing is running the same calculation and outputting the same result on each keyup event - you never use the value of `TimeAndMaterialsRate` that the user has entered!. And you should learn to use [Unobtrusive_JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is a slight syntax error with the end of your string. The last plus sign is in the wrong place. It should be like this:

```
new { onkeyup = "getAmount("+@Model.AdminFee+","+@Model.TimeAndMaterialsRate+","+@Model.TotalTimeSpent+","+@Model.MinimumCharge+")" })
```

Comment: a sorry, i actually edited it in the post since I deleted it from my original code, thanks anyways

Comment: In that case, you have the cases wrong in your javascript. Its Math.round() not math.Round()

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to use eval, but it's preety bad practice because it can be really injected & stuff.

Look at this article http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/

What you need is :

```
// function name and parameters to pass
var fnstring = "runMe";
var fnparams = [1, 2, 3];

// find object
var fn = window[fnstring];

// is object a function?
if (typeof fn === "function") fn.apply(null, fnparams);
```

Your params will look like :

```
var fnparams = {
minimumCharge : '@Model.MinimumCharge', 
... // and so on
};
```

And you will get them in this way :

```
parseInt(fnparams.minimumCharge);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt